# ASP:Login - call Javascript function on wrong password/username

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the ASP.net `ASP:Login`, and i want to call a javascript function if login fails.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a javascript function all ready on page, or you can add them later when the login fail. So first capture the login fail...

on your login module you add the event

```
<asp:Login OnLoginError="OnLoginError"  ... >
```

on code behind ether you open the javascript, ether you register a new one.

```
protected void OnLoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // this
  txtMsg.Visible = true;

  // OR this
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
               page.GetType(), "MsgFail", "alert('Login fail');", true);
}
```

Let say that you have a javasscript like this one for the first case.

```
<asp:literal run="server" id="txtMsg" EnableViewState="false" visible="false">
<script>
  alert("login fails");
</script>
</asp:literal>
```

Comment: The jS function i want call is     function periodical() {
        $('#shaker').effect('shake', { times: 10 }, 100);
    }

Comment: @ClemenGronver just place it where the alert is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegisterStartupScript` from codebehind.

```
protected void OnLoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                       GetType(), "SomeName", "SomeFunction();", true);
}
```

Where `SomeFunction()` is the javascript function you want to call.